# why is my pam_userdb.so missing?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ftp-client, pam, vsftpd

I want to use vsftpd to create a guest user , so I appended these to `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`:

```
auth    required /lib64/security/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd_virtual_accounts
account required /lib64/security/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd_virtual_accounts
```

But I can't find the `pam_userdb.so` file in `/lib64/security` and `/lib/security`.
And `find / pam_userdb.so` shows "no such file or directory".

How can I get the `pam_userdb.so` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the path; this is sufficient:

```
auth required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd_virtual_accounts
```

Your find command is incorrect; you need `find / -name pam_userdb.so`. Add `-print -quit` to stop on the first match.

On my system it's `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_userdb.so`.